# Connecting to SQL Server via .NET Integrated Security after password expiry

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I am a little confused with a behaviour I am seeing when using .NET to connect to a SQL Server. I believe this may have something to do with connection pools and I am hoping somebody may be able to explain why, and potentially make any suggestions on how to avoid this behaviour

I have an application running on multiple machines which opens some SQL connections to the server with Integrated Security. Then, when the account expires (password requires change), the SQL connection continues to work on certain machines. On some machines, though, the connections will be rejected, as the account has expired. The latter is the behaviour I would expect.

The configuration and connection mechanisms are exactly equal on all machines.

Could anybody help to explain why some queries work after the password has expired? And are there any tips on avoiding this, or can it not be helped?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending upon the size and layout of your AD Network you will see some latency in regards to password changes/expirations because different Domain Controllers may be servicing the Authentication Requests.

If you are using the Users Credentials for the SQL connection there isn't much you can do.  But if you are using a Service Account to make the SQL connection a better approach then using a single account is to use two accounts.  Before the first account's password expires create a new password for the second account and wait for it to replicate through your network.  24 hours if you have a large international network, less if you have a smaller network.  Then change your application services to use the second account.  Repeat the process using the first account before the second accounts password expires.

Another approach if you are running in a Windows Service is to use the built-in NetworkService account to make your SQL Connection.  Then you wont have passwords to change and the incoming credential will look like DOMAIN\$MACHINENAME.

Comment: It is a global network so I imagine it must be delays in proprogation. Unfortunately the two steps you've suggested are ones we can't take here, at least not yet, as they breach existing security requirements. For now we will have to keep a close eye on it. Thanks for your help